NDVI for Landsat gives results for the entire world
I am trying to get NDVI from Landsat-8 for a region starting from 2013 uptil Sep 2024 in Google Earth Engine. I am attempting time series and am looking for results for every month for all these years plus a mean image for each year. I have tried multiple variations for my region and dates but I am getting results for the whole world. It is also unclear which year or month the resulting image is from. It is the same image for each and every variation. Also, for print size command, I always get the same number - 1771326. Could someone help me with that?
The following is my script:
var startDate = '2013-05-01'; // Replace with your desired start date
var endDate = '2024-09-30'; // Replace with your desired end date
var poly = ee.Geometry.Polygon( 
               [[[34.77572551068633, -1.4666913947479083], 
                 [35.86337199506133, -2.125543581222633],
                 [35.40194621381133, -3.376516615229993], 
                 [34.21542277631133, -2.5536522179077723]]]); // Area of interest

//var extent = 1
var l8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2');
    l8.filterBounds(poly)
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
    //.filterDate('2013-05-01', '2017-04-30')
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(10, 10, 'month'))  // Only Nov-Feb observations
    .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than', 40); // Adjust the cloud coverage threshold as needed

  // Function to mask clouds and shadows
var maskClouds = function(image) {
  // Bits 4 and 3 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = 1 << 4;
  var cloudsBitMask = 1 << 3;
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
      .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  // Return the masked image, scaled to reflectance, without the QA bands.
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000)
      .select("SR_B[0-9]*")
      .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}

print (l8.size()); 

//Apply cloud masking function to the image collection
var l8Masked = l8.map(maskClouds);

// Create a median composite image
var composite = l8Masked.median();
var nir = composite.select('SR_B5');
var red = composite.select('SR_B4');
var ndvi = nir.subtract(red).divide(nir.add(red)).rename('NDVI');
//Display the composite image on the map
//Map.centerObject(Extent, 10);
var ndviParams = {min: -0.3, max: 0.9, palette: ['blue', 'red', 'yellow', 'green', 'black']};
Map.addLayer(ndvi, ndviParams, 'NDVI image');
//Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['SR_B5', 'SR_B4', 'SR_B3'], min: 0, max: 0.25}, 'Composite Image');
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ndvi,
  description: 'Jan',
  folder: 'Test',
//region: Extent,
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 1e13,
  crs : 'EPSG:4326',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
})


Thanks @TomazicM for the edit.

It looks like the print issue is caused by not reassigning the filtered ImageCollection back to the l8 variable.
Additionally, to compute the NDVI for each year or year-month, you can use an approach that involves creating lists of years and months and then mapping a function over these lists to generate the desired results.
Here’s a code example that implements this approach:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/d8dcac5b55ffc9b74201a1e68a37bbfb
This script calculates the NDVI for Landsat 8, applying filtering by year and month, and creates annual and monthly composites for the region of interest.

Thank you! Sorry for replying so late. This is helpful, although I do not understand how to incorporate the cloud mask in it. It gives an error saying 'QA_PIXEL' is not a valid band.

In the Example repository, you can find pre-built scripts for cloud masking across different collections. I just copied and pasted the Landsat 8 cloud masking example into the code I provided. Here's the updated script (note that I removed the scaling step from the computeNDVI function): https://code.earthengine.google.com/5fbe4c33620308d0dc4056719f21481b

Thank you! I will give this a go :)

thank you! The changes to the code are very useful. The scaling was not a requirement here and now I can get data for each month.
